# Is there a way to use Spring Batch 5 default configuration and use Jackson Serializer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-batch, deserialization

I am working on a migration to Spring Batch 5, but am running into a problem with the migration. Spring Batch 5 has changed the [default serializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#execution-context-serialization-updates). According to this doc you need to make sure the Jackson Serializer is on your class path in order to be able to utilize it. It does not specify however how to enable the use of the serializer.

[This documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/24/spring-batch-5-0-goes-ga) indicates you can use the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation, and elsewhere I found you can extend the `DefaultBatchConfiguration` class to adjust this config. However [Spring Boot Documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes) discourages this and indicates that this will cause Spring Boot to backoff configuration.

When I utilize the `@EnableBatchProcessing` or `DefaultBatchConfiguration` our jobs no longer launch as they used to (I utilize the `--spring.batch.job.name` argument).

Is there a way to use the default configuration that Spring Boot 3 provides and use the Jackson Serializer without needing to completely take over the configuration of Spring Batch? The issue is that I have historical data utilizing the Jackson serializer/deserializer that no longer can be processed by the upgrade.

Comment: What if just declare a `JacksonExecutionContextStringSerializer` bean ?

Comment: @gdomo just attempted it, Spring Batch still utilizes the `DefaultExecutionContextSerializer` (which is base64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot 3 does not provide a feature to customize the serializer without taking full control on the Batch configuration (ie by using `@EnableBatchProcessing` or extending `DefaultBatchConfiguration`).

You can request that feature, I would endorse it.

In the meantime, you can define the serializer as a bean in the application context and tell Spring Batch to use it through `@EnableBatchProcessing(executionContextSerializerRef="yourJacksonSerializer")` or extend `DefaultBatchConfiguration` and override `getExecutionContextSerializer`.

I talked about this at Spring IO [here](https://youtu.be/xoPPTawF_vY?t=556).